# Peopleeditor on user selected

Tags: 2013, people-picker

I'm developing an app in Sharepoint 2013. I'm using PeoplePicker and my goal is to capture event when a user is selected. F.e. I type "Tho", press enter - no match found, but when I click on "Tho" I get users that fit my pattern and say select Thomas. I'd like to have an event on selecting Thomas or after I type Thomas, press enter and get a match.
I'd be very grateful for any help, I've already tried to find a solution but without success.

Greets,
Maciek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see "Events" [here](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.ru/2014/11/sharepoint-2013-client-side-people.html):

There’s few events available in the people picker control as described below. All of these events will get two parameters – first one is the people picker id and second parameter is an array of selected users.
On Control Value Changed

This event will be fired if anything changes, like if user type text, user select a user from auto-fill list or user removes selected user. You can easily hook into the event as shown below:

```
 this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan.OnValueChangedClientScript=function (peoplePickerId, selectedUsersInfo) {
        console.log('inside OnValueChangedClientScript');
    };
```

On Control Resolved Users Changed

This event will be fired as soon as an user is resolved ( i.e., a resolved user is selected). You can hook into the event as shown below:

```
 this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan.OnUserResolvedClientScript = function (peoplePickerId, selectedUsersInfo) {
        console.log('inside OnUserResolvedClientScript');
    };
```

On Control Validate

The people picker control validate it’s values – sometimes when values are changed or you can fire the event by yourself by calling the method ‘Validate’. You can hook into the event as shown below:

```
 this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan.OnControlValidateClientScript = function (peoplePickerId, selectedUsersInfo) {
        console.log('inside OnControlValidateClientScript');
    };
```

Comment: Wow, that's awsume, that's exactly what I was looking for ;) Cheers